# Accessing the slurm EXIT code from another shell scrip

Tags: shell, slurm

How can I access the exit code of each job from another script. 
I am trying to automate the process and submit batches of slurm jobs using a shell script. Is there anyway to access the exit code of each job?

Comment: Which is it? [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) or [Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/info)

Comment: accessing EXIT code of a job submitted by slurm, from a shell script

Comment: Then I suggest you remove the batch-file tag :)

Comment: Does the operating system information for the batch-file tag suit your question? Shell scrip**t**s are usually the domain of 'nix systems!

Answer (score 0):

here is an answer by an expert in a supercomputing center;
"exit code" by nature won't be available from within the job.  Typically the Slurm exit code is actually the exit code of the last command run within the job script"